# Telegram API - how to get files and stickers

Tags: telegram

I'm using telegram-link and have created a working Telegram client that receives updates as soon as someone sends them (I'm using TCP). This works for text messages but hangs in an unexpected way if the users send files or stickers.

What is wrong here / missing? I'm listening for those events using registerOnUpdates which is defined as:

```
// The code:
Client.prototype.registerOnUpdates = function (callback) {
    manageUpdatesListener.call(this, 'on', callback);
};

function manageUpdatesListener  (func, callback) {
    var emitter = this._channel.getParser();
    emitter[func]('api.type.UpdatesTooLong', callback);
    emitter[func]('api.type.UpdateShortMessage', callback);
    emitter[func]('api.type.UpdateShortChatMessage', callback);
    emitter[func]('api.type.UpdateShort', callback);
    emitter[func]('api.type.UpdatesCombined', callback);
    emitter[func]('api.type.Updates', callback);
}
```

My best guess is that it is not listening to some of the "newer" update types, but I don't know which one to listen for.

Comment: telegram-link has not been updated for a long time. consider switching to tdcli or use webogram as a starting point.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but found some complications in that so I posted another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260148/how-to-listen-for-telegram-messages-push-notifications-in-webogram

Comment: Ill give it a look, never really looked much into webogram. Im also working on a nodejs library for pwrtelegram, it allows for listening for user messages, but I have not implemented that yet.

Comment: thanks for your help, looking forward to that