# How to listen for Telegram messages / push notifications in webogram

Tags: telegram

I need to receive latest telegram updates through the Telegram API. It seems that webogram is the only up-to-date javascript library for the task. I was using telegram link previously which did the task fine over TCP.

I want to know if webogram can do the same, and specifically what methods to use for receiving incoming messages / push notifications.

Comment: hi. I thought you had sorted this one out already?

Comment: that was telegram link, not webogram

Comment: See the approach I used below to tag webogram source code with console.logs. It would help you find out how the pieces of webogram fit together.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had given up getting any answers!

Comment: Webogram was a good learning / testing tool for me when I was getting started with Telegram

Answer (score 0):

The log below is from webogram.

I've added some comments with `console.log` to show what functions are being called and some extra response details.

This is for an older version of webogram (Layer 45) from Jan 2016, but all in all I doubt the basics have changed much.

You can similarly add console.logs throughout the source javascript and run a local copy of webogram to help you understand the process flow.

That's basically how I got these logs and details out of webogram.

Hope this helps.

```
ID  time    info    log
121 12:26:35.318    new Auth    Auth successfull! dc= 2 mtproto.js:479:15
127 12:26:35.325    CALL    =>> API call help.getNearestDc Object {  } Object { dcID: 2, createNetworker: true } mtproto.js:749:4
128 12:26:35.327    enc-START   [invokeWithLayer] 45 mtproto.js:753:7
168 12:26:35.551    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.51/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 708ms]
189 12:26:36.522    msg-r   <<=m [msg_container] Object { _: "msg_container", messages: Array[2] } mtproto.js:1452:5
190 12:26:36.523    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200678614200321", seqno: 1, bytes: 28, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
191 12:26:36.525    msg-r   <<=m [new_session_created] Object { _: "new_session_created", first_msg_id: "6242200671500883244", unique_id: "645797764649391412", server_salt: "17212767594123551779" } mtproto.js:1452:5
192 12:26:36.526    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200678630513665", seqno: 3, bytes: 28, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
193 12:26:36.528    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200671500883244", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
257 12:26:39.239    new Auth    Auth successfull! dc= 4 mtproto.js:479:15
270 12:26:59.606    CALL    =>> API call auth.sendCode Object { phone_number: "2348022002298", sms_type: 5, api_id: 38665, api_hash: "880c7847a517fc455d7d54731e90ad4e", lang_code: "en-US" } Object { dcID: 2, createNetworker: true } mtproto.js:749:4
321 12:27:00.048    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.51/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 422ms]
328 12:27:00.981    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200779464550396", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
331 12:27:00.986    CALL    =>> API call auth.sendCode Object { phone_number: "2348022002298", sms_type: 5, api_id: 38665, api_hash: "880c7847a517fc455d7d54731e90ad4e", lang_code: "en-US" } Object { dcID: "4", createNetworker: true, resultType: "auth.SentCode", messageID: "6242200779464550396" } mtproto.js:749:4
332 12:27:00.987    enc-START   [invokeWithLayer] 45 mtproto.js:753:7
377 12:27:01.288    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 321ms]
398 12:27:02.170    msg-r   <<=m [msg_container] Object { _: "msg_container", messages: Array[2] } mtproto.js:1452:5
399 12:27:02.171    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200787684582401", seqno: 1, bytes: 28, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
400 12:27:02.172    msg-r   <<=m [new_session_created] Object { _: "new_session_created", first_msg_id: "6242200784556418516", unique_id: "13396961033572361155", server_salt: "7076519506215495914" } mtproto.js:1452:5
401 12:27:02.173    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200787775901697", seqno: 3, bytes: 48, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
402 12:27:02.174    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200784556418516", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
407 12:27:02.344    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25154ms]
414 12:27:03.068    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200779464550396" } mtproto.js:1452:5
420 12:27:15.639    CALL    =>> API call auth.sendSms Object { phone_number: "2348022002298", phone_code_hash: "696b5befd8e809de81" } Object { dcID: "4", createNetworker: true, resultType: "auth.SentCode", messageID: "6242200784556418516" } mtproto.js:749:4
468 12:27:15.924    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 457ms]
475 12:27:17.154    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200848242727644", result: true } mtproto.js:1452:5
482 12:27:27.511    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200848242727644" } mtproto.js:1452:5
505 12:27:31.003    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.51/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25161ms]
511 12:27:40.133    CALL    =>> API call auth.signIn Object { phone_number: "2348022002298", phone_code_hash: "696b5befd8e809de81", phone_code: "26914" } Object { dcID: "4", createNetworker: true, resultType: "Bool", messageID: "6242200848242727644" } mtproto.js:749:4
560 12:27:40.454    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 756ms]
567 12:27:41.223    msg-r   <<=m [msg_container] Object { _: "msg_container", messages: Array[2] } mtproto.js:1452:5
568 12:27:41.224    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200956100910081", seqno: 7, bytes: 80, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
569 12:27:41.225    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200954555850604", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
570 12:27:41.226    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200956751929345", seqno: 9, bytes: 88, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
571 12:27:41.227    msg-r   <<=m [updates] Object { _: "updates", updates: Array[1], users: Array[0], chats: Array[0], date: 1453375666, seq: 2 } mtproto.js:1452:5
579 12:27:41.758    CALL    =>> API call updates.getState Object {  } Object { noErrorBox: true } mtproto.js:749:4
586 12:27:41.842    CALL    =>> API call account.updateStatus Object { offline: false } Object { noErrorBox: true } mtproto.js:749:4
594 12:27:41.850    CALL    =>> API call messages.getDialogs Object { offset_date: 0, offset_id: 0, offset_peer: Object, limit: 20 } Object { timeout: 300 } mtproto.js:749:4
655 12:27:42.965    CALL    =>> API call messages.getAllStickers Object { hash: "" } Object {  } mtproto.js:749:4
696 12:27:43.920    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 908ms]
712 12:27:44.613    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 303ms]
727 12:27:46.488    msg-r   <<=m [msg_container] Object { _: "msg_container", messages: Array[3] } mtproto.js:1452:5
728 12:27:46.489    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970862778369", seqno: 11, bytes: 36, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
729 12:27:46.489    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960159395644", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
730 12:27:46.490    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970891641857", seqno: 13, bytes: 776, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
731 12:27:46.492    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960356118244", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
732 12:27:46.494    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970897958913", seqno: 15, bytes: 16, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
733 12:27:46.495    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960337591900", result: true } mtproto.js:1452:5
740 12:27:46.567    msg-r   <<=m [msg_container] Object { _: "msg_container", messages: Array[4] } mtproto.js:1452:5
741 12:27:46.568    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970862778369", seqno: 11, bytes: 36, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
742 12:27:46.569    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960159395644" } mtproto.js:1452:5
743 12:27:46.569    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970891641857", seqno: 13, bytes: 776, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
744 12:27:46.570    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960356118244" } mtproto.js:1452:5
745 12:27:46.571    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970897958913", seqno: 15, bytes: 16, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
746 12:27:46.572    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960337591900" } mtproto.js:1452:5
747 12:27:46.573    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200973791209473", seqno: 17, bytes: 76, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
748 12:27:46.574    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200964892679524", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
754 12:27:46.584    CALL    =>> API call messages.getStickerSet Object { stickerset: Object } Object {  } mtproto.js:749:4
811 12:27:47.346    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 539ms]
818 12:27:48.175    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200981275507620", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
857 12:27:49.351    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25141ms]
864 12:27:57.219    msg-r   <<=m [msgs_ack] Object { _: "msgs_ack", msg_ids: Array[0] } mtproto.js:1452:5
870 12:28:04.673    CALL    =>> API call messages.readHistory Object { peer: Object, max_id: 0 } Object {  } mtproto.js:749:4
908 12:28:04.860    CALL    =>> API call messages.getHistory Object { peer: Object, offset_id: 16, add_offset: 0, limit: 20 } Object { timeout: 300, noErrorBox: true } mtproto.js:749:4
922 12:28:05.713    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 367ms]
929 12:28:06.096    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242201058769372356", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
936 12:28:15.702    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242201058769372356" } mtproto.js:1452:5
977 12:28:16.122    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25170ms]
983 12:28:26.637    CALL    =>> API call account.updateStatus Object { offline: true } Object { noErrorBox: true } mtproto.js:749:4
1016    12:28:26.660    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 302ms]
1023    12:28:27.062    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242201153183272948", result: true } mtproto.js:1452:5
1030    12:28:41.985    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242201153183272948" } mtproto.js:1452:5
1071    12:28:42.421    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25165ms]
```